# How to bind data that is saved to a file with other data that is saved to another file c#

Tags: c#, data-binding

I am making a c# maths test console-application, and I just made user accounts.

I have one file that contains all the account details and another file that saves the difficulty level they did the last time they did the test and the score they got.

Here is my class for saving the difficulty level and score:

```
public class SaveLastTestResults
    {
        [Serializable]
        public class ToFile
        {
            public int TotalScore { get; private set; }
            public int NumberOfQuestions { get; }
            public UserDifficulty UserDifficulty { get; }
            public ToFile(int numberOfQuestions, UserDifficulty userDifficulty, int totalScore)
            {
                NumberOfQuestions = numberOfQuestions;
                UserDifficulty = userDifficulty;
                TotalScore = totalScore;
            }
        }

        public class SaveToFile
        {
            public static void SerializeLastTest(int numberOfQuestions, int totalScore, UserDifficulty userDifficulty)
            {
                ToFile obj = new ToFile(numberOfQuestions, userDifficulty, totalScore);
                IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                Stream stream = new FileStream("LastTest.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                formatter.Serialize(stream, obj);
                stream.Close();
            }
            public static ToFile DeserializeLastTest()
            {
                Stream stream = new FileStream("LastTest.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                ToFile objnew = (ToFile)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
                stream.Close();
                return objnew;
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is my class that saves the account details:

```
public class UserLogin
    {
        [Serializable]
        public class User
        {
            public string UserName { get; set; }
            public string Password { get; set; }
            public User(string userName, string password)
            {
                UserName = userName;
                Password = password;
            }
        }
        [Serializable]
        public class Users
        {
            public List<User> Accounts;
            public Users() => Accounts = new List<User>();

            public void SerializeAccountDetails(string filePath)
            {
                IFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                using (Stream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                    bf.Serialize(fs, this);
            }

            public static Users DeserializeAccountDetails(string filePath)
            {
                IFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                using (Stream sr = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
                    return bf.Deserialize(sr) as Users;
            }

            public bool ContainsUserName(string userName) =>
                Accounts.Any(x => x.UserName == userName);

            public bool ContainsAccount(string userName, string password) =>
                Accounts.Any(x => x.UserName == userName && x.Password == password);

            public bool AddAccountDetails(string userName, string password)
            {
                Accounts.Add(new User(userName, password));
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is my class where I remind them of the difficulty they tried and the score they got:

```
public static UserDifficulty SuggestingDifficulty()
        {
            ToFile objnew = SaveToFile.DeserializeLastTest("LastText.txt");
            Console.WriteLine($"Last time you did the test on {objnew.UserDifficulty} level and got {objnew.TotalScore}/{objnew.NumberOfQuestions}");
        }
```

And this is my Main method:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("To Login Type 1, To Create a new account Type 2");
            int LogInOrSignUp;
            do
            {
                int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out LogInOrSignUp);
            } while (LogInOrSignUp != 1 && LogInOrSignUp != 2);

            var filePath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "AccountDetails.txt");
            var userName = "";
            var password = "";
            var successfull = false;
            var userDetails = Users.DeserializeAccountDetails(filePath);

            if (userDetails is null)
                userDetails = new Users();

            while (!successfull)
            {
                if (LogInOrSignUp == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Write your username:");
                    userName = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter your password:");
                    password = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (userDetails.ContainsAccount(userName, password))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You have logged in successfully!");
                        successfull = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Your username or password is incorect, try again!");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter a username:");
                    userName = Console.ReadLine();

                    if (userDetails.ContainsUserName(userName))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("The username is taken. Try another one.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter a password:");
                        password = Console.ReadLine();

                        successfull = true;
                        userDetails.AddAccountDetails(userName, password);
                        userDetails.SerializeAccountDetails(filePath);
                        Console.WriteLine($"A new account for {userName} has been created.");
                    }
                }
            }
            UserDifficulty userSuggestingDifficulty = CanUseManyTimes.SuggestingDifficulty();
            var (userDifficulty, numberOfQuestions, autoDifficultyInput, numberOfSeconds) = UserInputs();

            if (autoDifficultyInput == "Y")
            {
                userDifficulty = userSuggestingDifficulty;
            }

            var score = RunTest(numberOfQuestions, userDifficulty, numberOfSeconds);

            Console.WriteLine($"Total score: {score.TotalScore} of {numberOfQuestions}");

            if (userDifficulty == UserDifficulty.Easy)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Addition score: {score.AdditionScore} of {score.AdditionQuestion}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Subtraction score: {score.SubtractionScore} of {score.SubtractionQuestion}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Multiplication score: {score.MultiplicationScore} of {score.MultiplicationQuestion}");
            }
            else if (userDifficulty == UserDifficulty.Normal)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Addition score: {score.AdditionScore} of {score.AdditionQuestion}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Subtraction score: {score.SubtractionScore} of {score.SubtractionQuestion}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Multiplication score: {score.MultiplicationScore} of {score.MultiplicationQuestion}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Division score: {score.DivisionScore} of {score.DivisionQuestion}");
            }
            else if (userDifficulty == UserDifficulty.Hard)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Multipication score: {score.MultiplicationScore} of {score.MultiplicationQuestion}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Division score: {score.DivisionScore} of {score.DivisionQuestion}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Power score: {score.PowerScore} of {score.PowerQuestion}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Squareroot score: {score.SquareRootScore} of {score.SquareRootQuestion}");
            }
            SaveToFile.SerializeLastTest(numberOfQuestions, score.TotalScore, userDifficulty);
        }
    }
}
```

How would I make it so the score and difficulty the user got last time they took the test is different for each account?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Thinks like that. Have U thought abt using ETL? Combining data from different data sources and generate a new data set seems to be a fit for ETL

Comment: @cscmh99 could you show me how I would implement that in my code because other examples look really complicated

Comment: ETL means .... tools like sqlserver SSIS. Didn’t even need to write any code in ur case

Comment: @cscmh99 not sure what you mean, do I need to download some extension?

Comment: SSIS should be part of SqlServer. Dun get me wrong. You can still do that by C#. It’s just ... SSIS has built-in function to load data from files, output to file and whatever data massage features. It’s just less effort.

Comment: thanks @cscmh99 but the existing answer seems simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you create file per user ? You can just change "SuggestingDifficulty" functions to get the username and use it as file name ?

```
public static UserDifficulty SuggestingDifficulty(string userName)
{
    ToFile objnew = SaveToFile.DeserializeLastTest($"{userName}.txt");
    Console.WriteLine($"Last time you did the test on {objnew.UserDifficulty} level and got {objnew.TotalScore}/{objnew.NumberOfQuestions}");
}
```

and

```
public static void SerializeLastTest(int numberOfQuestions, int totalScore, UserDifficulty userDifficulty,string userName)
{
    ToFile obj = new ToFile(numberOfQuestions, userDifficulty, totalScore);
    IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    Stream stream = new FileStream("${userName}.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    formatter.Serialize(stream, obj);
    stream.Close();
}

public static ToFile DeserializeLastTest(string userName)
{
    Stream stream = new FileStream($"{userName}.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    ToFile objnew = (ToFile)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    stream.Close();
    return objnew;
}
```

Comment: hi, @SerhatDev your solution seems to be working but the only problem is every time I create a new account the code ends and says "Could not find file {username}.txt"

Comment: I know how to fix it but I will have to keep on doing this again and again, every time I create a new account

Comment: I figured my problem out! Thanks so much for the help! I'll award the bounty to you when I can 